# Evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_0^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n dx$

Tags: integration, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_0^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n dx$$

The answer should be $1$.

I tried to solve it similar to how one user solved this integral [Limit of integral with cos and sin](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2170465/limit-of-integral-with-cos-and-sin)

but it seems like it doesn't work because the upper bound will become $1 - \pi/4$.

Comment: What upper bound is $1-\pi/4$?  Mind explaining what you mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know how to deal with

$$n \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\cos x - \sin x)^n\,dx,$$

just split the integral at $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and see whether you can find something useful for the other part.

Since $x \mapsto \cos x - \sin x$ is strictly decreasing on $\bigl[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\bigr]$, and $\cos \frac{\pi}{4} = \sin \frac{\pi}{4}$, we have

$$\lvert \cos x - \sin x\rvert \leqslant c := \sin 1 - \cos 1$$

for $\frac{\pi}{4} \leqslant x \leqslant 1$. Hence

$$\Biggl\lvert \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n\,dx\Biggr\rvert \leqslant \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^1 c^n\,dx < c^n.$$

Since $0 < c < 1$, it follows that

$$n \int_{\frac{\pi}{4}}^1 (\cos x - \sin x)^n\,dx \to 0.$$

That is useful indeed. Thus we need only consider

$$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\cos x - \sin x)^n\,dx = 2^{n/2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin^n \biggl(\frac{\pi}{4} - x\biggr)\,dx = 2^{n/2}\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin^n x\,dx.$$

Substituting $u = \sin x$, then $v = \sqrt{2}\cdot u$, and afterwards integrating by parts, we find (for $n \geqslant 1$)

\begin{align}
n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\cos x - \sin x)^n\,dx
&= n 2^{n/2} \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \sin^n x\,dx \\
&= n 2^{n/2} \int_0^{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}} \frac{u^n}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\,du \\
&= n \int_0^1 \frac{v^n}{\sqrt{2-v^2}}\,dv \\
&= v^n\cdot \frac{v}{\sqrt{2-v^2}}\biggr\rvert_0^1 - \int_0^1 v^n\biggl(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2-v^2}} + \frac{v^2}{(2-v^2)^{3/2}}\biggr)\,dv \\
&= 1 - \int_0^1 \frac{2v^n}{(2-v^2)^{3/2}}\,dv.
\end{align}

Since $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} < \frac{2}{(2-v^2)^{3/2}} < 2$ for $0 < v < 1$, we thus have

$$1 - \frac{2}{n+1} < n\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} (\cos x - \sin x)^n\,dx < 1 - \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\,(n+1)}.$$

Answer (score 6):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> [Laplace Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method):

\begin{align}
&\lim_{n \to \infty}\braces{%
n\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\cos\pars{x} - \sin\pars{x}}^{\,n}\,\dd x} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{%
n\int_{0}^{\infty}\expo{-nx}\,\dd x} = \bbx{1}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

This answer is base on integration by parts and Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

If $0<x<1$ then $-1 < \cos(x)-\sin(x)<1$ and $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n = 0$. Thus

\begin{gather*}
n\int_{0}^{1}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n\, dx =\\[2ex] n\int_{0}^{1}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^n(-\sin(x)-\cos(x))\dfrac{-1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\, dx =\\[2ex]
\left[\dfrac{n}{n+1}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^{n+1}\dfrac{-1}{\sin(x)+\cos(x)}\right]_{0}^{1}-\\[2ex]\dfrac{n}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^{n+2}\dfrac{1}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2}\, dx = \\[2ex]
\dfrac{n}{n+1} -\dfrac{n}{n+1}(\cos(1)-\sin(1))^{n+1}\dfrac{1}{\sin(1)+\cos(1)}-\\[2ex]\dfrac{n}{n+1}\int_{0}^{1}(\cos(x)-\sin(x))^{n+2}\dfrac{1}{(\sin(x)+\cos(x))^2}\, dx \to 1-0-0 = 1, \quad n \to \infty .
\end{gather*}